# Hosting WCF Service for LAN

Tags: wcf, windows-services, wcf-binding, lan

I have to host a WCF service in a windows service. This WCF service will be used in a local area network. Which binding is used in such scenario?

Comment: Will the consumers of the service be WCF also?

Comment: No. It is a desktop appplication.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it should not really matter if you are using the WCF on a LAN, WAN or Internet. It should be dependent on what kind of application you are writing to serve as a client. Please read more and analyze your application to use the correct binding: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733033(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well since you are in LAN , if your client applications will be .NET applications then you better choose NetTcpBidning it will boost your performance since it's TCP protocol

but anyway the binding you will choose wouldn't matter and your service will be functional either way